# How to fix div position while scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I want to scroll div2 on mouse scroll without scrolling div1 and div3. What I want is when I scroll, position of div1 and div3 should be fixed. In our example when I scroll all the div scrolls , meaning div1 and div3 goes away from the screen. So I want to fix position of those divs. I have tried to achieve that using css(look at jsFiddle link), but failed. Kindly give some suggestions how can I able to scroll only div2 whereas div1 and div3's position should not be changed.
Thanks in advance.

> Link Demo : [`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/sucx1t6z/)

```css
.Div1 {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 24%;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #c00;
  margin-right: 5px;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.Div2 {
  min-height: 1000px;
  width: 45%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: green;
  float: left
}

.Div3 {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 24%;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #c00;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; min-height: 200px;">
  <div class="Div1">
    Div1
  </div>

  <div class="Div2">Div2</div>

  <div class="Div3">
    Div3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried and where you failed. Also Link Demo us not working

Comment: Use `position:fixed;`

Comment: ..and use position absolute in div2.

Comment: You can try to my jsfiddle  . After Send link

Comment: Hello @BhojendraNepal thanks for your reply. I hav tried it using position:fixed but what it does is , all divs are overlapped.

Comment: @DawidPi , Thanks for your reply and inconvenience regretted.   Here I have updated my jsFiddle link. Please go through it and revert me with solutions. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one , you can get your solution.

```css
.Div1 {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 24%;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #c00;
  margin-right: 5px;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
}

.Div2 {
  min-height: 1000px;
  width: 45%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 28.5%;
}

.Div3 {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 24%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #c00;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; min-height: 200px;">
  <div class="Div1"> Div1</div>
  <div class="Div2">Div2</div>
  <div class="Div3"> Div3 </div>
</div>
```

This may helps you , and this is the [JS Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sucx1t6z/1/)

Answer (score 1):

### HTML

```
<aside class="thing-one">
    aside one
</aside>

<section class="main-content">
    <ul>
        <li>main content</li>
        <li>main content</li>
        <li>main content</li>
        <li>main content</li>
        <li>main content</li>
        ...
    </ul>
</section>

<aside class="thing-two">
    aside two
</aside>
```

### CSS

```
/* global */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

/* specific */
.thing-one, .thing-two {
    width: 25%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.thing-one {
    left: 0;
    background: yellow;
}

.thing-two {
    right: 0;
    background: red;
}

.main-content {
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/sucx1t6z/4/)

Comment: It's nice to just tear things like this down and build them again often. : )

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking like this check the code, I hope It will helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 1){
      $('.wrap').addClass('sticky')
    }
    else($('.wrap').removeClass("sticky"))
  });
});
```

```css
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
.Div1
{
    border: 1px solid #ddd;width:24%; background-color: white;float:left;border: 2px solid #c00;margin-right:5px;
    min-height:50px;
    left:0;
}
.Div2
{
    min-height: 1000px; width: 48%;/*overflow: auto; */background-color: green; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 9px;
}

.Div3
{
    width:24%; background-color: white;border: 2px solid #c00;
    min-height:50px;
    float: right;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
}
.wrap{
    width: 100%; min-height: 200px;position:relative;
}
.wrap.sticky .Div1 ,.wrap.sticky .Div3{
    position: fixed;
}
.wrap.sticky .Div2{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="Div1">
         Div1
    </div>
 
    <div class="Div2">Div2</div>
 
     <div class="Div3">
         Div3
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. It wont work for me. It is the same as I posted in jsFiddle. Div1 and Div2 are not still fixed. It goes away when I scroll the page.

Comment: Ohh really, did you check running code in snippet `Div1` and `Div2` is fixed when you scroll.

Comment: Sorry Maddy, It wont work from here.. but when I created a new jsFiddle and test it works. As I can see that div1 and div3 are fixed. but when I scrolls div3 will goes up. Here is that jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/xC2YH/33/ and notice that I have remove body element from css.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xC2YH/34/

Comment: Hurrey, It really works. We are almost there.. But when I scroll, div2 gets fluctuates a little bit. Let me know is it possible to make is stable and smooth. If so then it would be more useful. Once again thanks for your solution. I will appreciate your time and efforts. Thanks again. :)

Comment: That fluctuates because of `Div2`    `margin-left: 9px;` you have to manage it and thanks for your appreciation.you can upvote or accept answer.